# Universal Data Link - File cannot be opened. Ensure it is a valid Data Link file

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am attempting to create a UDL file programmatically in C#. In my program, I want to show the user the Data Link properties window but with my own default values for the connection string. I initially thought to do the following:

```
string[] lines = new string[]
{
    "[oledb]",
    "; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring",
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False"
};

File.WriteAllLines("Test.udl", lines);
Process p = Process.Start("Test.udl");
p.WaitForExit();
```

However, I get this error when trying to open the file:

> File cannot be opened. Ensure it is a valid Data Link file.

This is strange because I created an empty file, named it `something.udl`, opened it, clicked `OK`, and then opened the contents of the file which was:

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False
```

But there was a newline character at the end of the connection string. I used KDiff to compare the this file and the file I created in my program and it said the "Files are equal text but the they are not binary equal" or something to that effect.

I believe it has to do with how the `File.WriteAllLines` method writes the strings. So I attempted to use different encodings with the method but with no success. Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

I am using [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx) as a reference about UDL files. Its also interesting to note that if I open a new text file and past in all of the lines in my `lines` array, I arrive at the same error.

Comment: [tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use the Unicode encoding:

```
File.WriteAllLines("Test.udl", lines, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: While I'm sure this solution works great, I was able to use the `Encoding.GetEncoding` method to write the file with proper encoding. I like to not write code that is already available in the libraries I am using.

Comment: Just to clairify, my comment above was directed toward your solution before you modified your answer...

Yup, this is correct. I found in KDiff that the working UDL file is encoded with UTF-16 which is Unicode. So I used `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16")`

Answer (score 0):

When creating the file in a plain-text editor, use the UTF-16 Little Endian encoding and include a Byte Order Mark (since Microsoft started on the Intel platform they consider that the "default" when they talk about UTF-16).

When using a program, make sure to use that particular encoding as well, programming languages might still default to a legacy codepage or use UTF-8, in which case opening the UDL file will trigger the error shown in the question.